# select display:none element using selenium or splinter

Tags: python, forms, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

i need to emulate add ad in this site http://chance.ru/add
have this code

```
browser.visit('http://chance.ru/add')
browser.execute_script('document.getElementById("edit-category").style.display = "block"')
browser.select('category', '407')
browser.driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
```

writed on splinter(http://splinter.cobrateam.info/, it's like selenium)
**select** with id **edit-category** has display:none and i cannot select this by webdriver.. i tried run javascript and change css style to display:block, but i failed.. it returns **Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated** again